# Make right div resizable

Tags: html, css, layout

I have two divs in another div container on the page. I want to make first div fix width and the second div rsizable.

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="first"></div>
 <div id="second">                    
       <input id="edit" />
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#first {
            width: 140px;
            height: 50px;
            float:left;
        }
#second
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 140px;
            width: 100%;
        }
#container {
        width: 100%;
        position:relative;
}
```

But in this case the second div go out from the container on the right side. How to make second div resizable started from the right side of the first div to the end of container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. https://jsfiddle.net/o7e5x0p0/2/

```
#first {
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
}

#second {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 75%;
  background: green;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But also I need <input id="edit" /> set 100% width inside second div. But in this case its get 100% of container and jump under the first div. How to make objects inside second div resizeble too?

Comment: But I need first div fixed width

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with **Flexbox**. With `flex: 1;` on `#second` div, it will take rest of space on right.
[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x9zj7ftf/)

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

#first {
  width: 150px;
  background: blue;
}

#second {
  flex: 1;
  background: #939A9F;
}

#second input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="first"></div>
 <div id="second">                    
      <input type="text">
 </div>
</div>
```

Or you can do this with **CSS table** 
[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x9zj7ftf/1/)

```css
#container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#first {
  width: 150px;
  background: blue;
  display: table-cell;
}

#second {
  background: #939A9F;
  display: table-cell;
}

#second input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="first"></div>
 <div id="second">                    
      <input type="text">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in `second` div change all to `overflow: hidden` and `input` `width: 100%` :

```
#first {
  width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}

#second {
  overflow: hidden;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle-link](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/drLn0ud3/)